# Тень кнопок в API 22 и 21 как убрать?

Tags: android, button

Ребята подскажите как убрать тень и обводку кнопки. Сам их не задавал, в версиях апи от 15 до 19 ее нет, появляется только в версии андроид 5.0  и выше (апи 21 и 22). скрины прилагаю. Кнопка идет в цвет фона и тень вообще не в тему... поскажите... использую бекгроунд дравбл хмл

[image: апи 21]
[image: апи 22]

Comment: android:style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" - решение оказалось простым...

Answer (score 2):

(решение из комментария)

```
android:style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```